# Trying to keep it unicode all the way

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, http-headers

Arabic user data that was submitted from a website form occasionally ends up [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake#Arabic) in our database. A user would type something like:

> الإعلان العالمى لحقوق الإنسان

in an input form and the post is received by a server and stored in a database. When we retrieve the message from the database, it reads:

> ï»¿Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ø¹Ù„Ø§Ù† Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù‰ Ù„Ø­Ù‚ÙˆÙ‚ Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ù†Ø³Ø§Ù†

The form is in an embedded iframe page with these tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />

    <!-- other header elements -->

  </head>

  <body>
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="post">

   <!-- other body elements -->

  </body>

</html>
```

A post generate these request headers

```
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  543
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host    www.salesforce.com
Origin  [ -- redacted -- ]
Pragma  no-cache
Referer [ -- redacted -- ]
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0 FirePHP/0.7.4
x-insight   activate
```

And receives these response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 25 Apr 2014 09:15:49 GMT
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I have no control over the server configuration of the machine serving the form or the server processing the form data.

Is there anything more I can do in the page markup that can prevent the problem? Are there known user agents which would ignore the `accept-charset` attribute?

Since the character scramble only happens occasionally, what is the best way to try and replicate / isolate the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You may be better off trying to work together with Salesforce to solve this than with random people on the internet.

Comment: Mojibake doesn't apply to databases. Can you explain further what the problem is?

Comment: What is the database, what programming language are you using how are you storing and retrieving from the database, what are you using to validate the database contents? Each one of these elements require encoding to be properly handled.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack as I say, due to multi-tenancy of the server I have no control over how the input is processed and stored into the database. I am focussing on the elements that I have control over. Can it be improved? When retrieving I use an Apex script, but I am pretty sure the conversion swap doesn't happen at that stage.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/implementation_considerations.htm#sforce_api_other_internationalization
"The API supports either full Unicode characters or ISO-8859-1 characters. The character set for your organization depends on the Salesforce instance your organization uses. If your organization logs into ssl.salesforce.com, then your encoding is ISO-8859-1. All other instances use UTF-8. You can determine the character set for your organization by calling describeGlobal() and inspecting the encoding value returned in the DescribeGlobalResult."

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas. We are not using the API, but it I will follow this lead and check the character set for our instance.